# Calculating percentage in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, division

Can someone help me with this problem I am using this query

```
SUM(AVGCOST) OVER (ORDER BY ITEM.NUM ASC)/(SUM(AVGCOST) OVER()) AS PERCENTAJE
```

And it's supposed to return a "percentage" (0.001, 0.3, etc.) that is accumulating but only returns me 0s and the last field returns me a 1

Comment: maybe you mean `partition by item.num asc` instead of `order by`?  ordering a sum doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense to me  (ranking, row_number would... but not a sum).  but partitioning by an item number does.

Comment: SO is a great site to ask questions and get answers: Just be sure to provide a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Before you ask a question consider [talking to the duck first](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/). Yes, I'm serious! To help us help you, generate sample data and expected results. [ascii table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) makes the output easy to read! You could also mock up data and the SQL tried using http://rextester.com/ or a similar site.  Pretty much anything is possible; it's a matter of should we do it; not can we.

Comment: What data type is `avgcost` ?

Comment: Sry for not answering but yes, it was the data type

Answer (score 0):

I already resolved it, I think it was the data type i just did this and now it works

```
SUM(AVGCOST) OVER (ORDER BY ITEM.NUM ASC)*1.000/(SUM(AVGCOST) OVER()) AS PERCENTAJE
```